# How to load file:// images in Cordova iOS platform?

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

I'm writing an app with Cordova, and want to genarate an ipa file from iOS platform. When I run my app in iOS simulator, everything works well. But when I generate an ad-hoc and install it on my iPhone, images won't load. Images are in app data and their URL starts with file://

Here are my plugins:

- cordova-plugin-dialogs
- cordova-plugin-file
- cordova-plugin-file-transfer
- cordova-plugin-network-information
- cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
- cordova-plugin-statusbar
- cordova-plugin-whitelist
- cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
- cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr

And my config.xml File:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0FPN.jpg

Answer (score 0):

That's a big bug, for `cordova-ios`, we still need to rely on outdated `@globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr` to have local assets (images, spritesheets, audios) working...